# Using cloudera scalats library in project using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, cloudera

I am trying to use cloudera scalats library for time series forecasting but unable to dowload the library using sbt.

Below is build.sbt file. I can see maven repo has 0.4.0 disted version, so not sure what wrong I am doing.

Can anyone please help me to know what wrong I am doing with sbt file?

```
import sbt.complete.Parsers._

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

name := "Forecast Stock Price using Spark TimeSeries library"

val sparkVersion = "1.5.2"

//resolvers ++= Seq("Cloudera Repository" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"     %% "spark-core"              % sparkVersion withSources(),
  "org.apache.spark"     %% "spark-streaming"         % sparkVersion withSources(),
  "org.apache.spark"     %% "spark-sql"               % sparkVersion withSources(),
  "org.apache.spark"     %% "spark-hive"              % sparkVersion withSources(),
  "org.apache.spark"     %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % sparkVersion withSources(),
  "org.apache.spark"     %% "spark-mllib"             % sparkVersion withSources(),
  "com.databricks"       %% "spark-csv"               % "1.3.0"      withSources(),
  "com.cloudera.sparkts" %% "sparkts"                 % "0.4.0"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  "com.cloudera.sparkts" %% "sparkts"                 % "0.4.0"
```

to

```
  "com.cloudera.sparkts" % "sparkts"                 % "0.4.0"
```

`sparkts` is only distributed for Scala 2.11; it does not encode the Scala version in the artifact name.